# Edit text in NSOutlineView like Finder

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

If you rename a file in the Finder, the text field expands horizontally up to about the width of the column. And then it expands vertically up to three rows before scrolling. I'm assuming this has to be done in a text field outside the outline view. And I can get a text field to resize while I type. I just don't know how to place it over the outline view when necessary. And keep it pinned to the row if the outline view scrolls. Does anyone have any insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text editing is handled by a dedicated `NSText` and it’s called “field editor”. This shared single view is used for all text editing that happens in the window. It’s separate from what usually displays the text (when not editing).

Here are the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419647-fieldeditor

As mentioned in the docs discussion section, you can use and customize another field editor. This should be a starting point for your task.

> The window’s delegate can substitute a custom field editor in place of the window’s field editor by implementing windowWillReturnFieldEditor(_:to:). The custom field editor can become the default editor (common to all text-displaying objects) or specific to a particular text-displaying object (object).

`NSControl` docs also have a section about Field Editor that might help.